# Access a link from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code

```
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(BaseUrl+Path);
var PdfArray = doc.Save();
doc.Close();
return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(PdfArray), "application/pdf");
```

The problem is that the link it tries to access (my own controller) are protected with [Authorized].

Is there a way to add the user in the link?

I want to access the function in this way /PDFTOCV/ID

There is a function in PDFTOCV that calls another controller where the ID is used to decide which CV to present, the issue is that when I try to access that function from PDFTOCV I am not able to authorize (even though I can access PDFTOCV which is protected in the same manner)

Below is the function used to create a PDF from a view.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> PDFCV(int Id)
{
  var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
  HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
  var BaseUrl = HttpContext.Request.Host;
  var Path = Url.Action("PreviewCv", "Cv", new { Id = Id});
  PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(BaseUrl+Path);
  var PdfArray = doc.Save();
  doc.Close();
  return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(PdfArray),"application/pdf");
}
```

The controller function used to create the view for PreviewCV.

```
 [Authorize]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PreviewCv(int id)
 {
     var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
     logic here
 }
```

The preview works when I access the PreviewCV directly.

Comment: I think this needs more detail it is unclear what you are asking for. Unless you want to access the `User` object available in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I would like to access the User. As you normally can access with using the UserManager, however since a controller doesn't (by default) includes the user in the link.

Comment: You need to authorize first and then you will be able to make requests to "protected" actions

Comment: The user is authorized, meaning that the user can access PDFTOCV which is protected in the same way, is there some way to include that authorization in the link?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen What authorization are you using, cookie, jwt or what? And please add full code of your actions with attributes, what action is called and what action needs user to be authorized

Comment: I am using cookie, I can add the functions.

Comment: Okay I think I know how to solve it but I need to know what nuget package are you using for converting html to pdf?

Comment: I am using selectPdf (https://selectpdf.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add authentication data to converter's request to access page being converted. Since you are using `Cookie` authentication you just need to make `HtmlToPdf` converter to use current authentication cookie

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
//default auth cookie name; set cookie name your application uses
string cookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
converter.Options.HttpCookies.Add(cookieName, HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName]);
```

Comment: This works when I run it locally, but when I publish to the IIS, it throws an exception, can you think of a reason for why this would happen?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen Hard to say, it shouldn't. What kind of exception?